# Angular 9 : Unable to redirect to a specific route in angular app after redirecting from an external url

Tags: javascript, angular, angular9

I have an angular app that is using version 9. From one of my routes(say, **/search/details/id**), I am redirecting to an external URL using the URL value I received from API response like

```
window.location.href = "https://www.payment.com";
```

Now I am getting redirected to the external payment page where I can make the payment or cancel the transaction.

If I click cancel I am redirected back to the previous page which is my angular app with route **/search/details/:id**. From here, if I click the browser back button, I am taken to the payment page at **https://www.payment.com**. I want to get navigated to the angular app **/search** route instead from which I initially navigated to /search/details/id.

I tried to handle the browser back button in the component in the following ways,

```
1. fromEvent(window, 'popstate')
      .subscribe((e) => {
        console.log(e, 'back button');
        this.router.navigate(
          ['/search']);
   });
   Added inside the constructor of the component corresponding to /search/details/:id

2. router.events.forEach((event) => {
      if(event instanceof NavigationStart) {
        if (event.navigationTrigger === 'popstate') {
          console.log(event, 'back button router');
        }
      }
    });
    Added inside constructor
3. @HostListener('window:popstate', ['$event'])
  onPopState(event) {
    this.router.navigate(
        ['search/']);
  }
  Inside the component
```

None of the above callbacks get triggered when I come back from the external page and click the browser back button from the/search/details/:id page. However, when I click on the browser back button from /search/details/id page without going to the external page, the above callbacks are getting triggered and it's taken to /search page.

So I think reloading the angular app after redirecting from the external prevents the popstate event to get triggered.

Any thoughts/solution is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Does not look possible to me. I don't think you can control the browser history when it concerns external URLs.

Comment: Is  https://www.payment.com also an angular app?

Comment: @Phalgun, payment.com is an external site which we don't have any control.

Comment: I would recommend upgrading to Angular 12 or higher and explore module federation approach. I'd used https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-architects/module-federation for customization.

Answer (score 1):

when you do `window.location.href = "https://www.payment.com";` you close the current app and open new app (the one provided by payment.com).

I think a good way to do what you have to do is create a new component with an iframe inside and open it as modal or popup.
Probably you hav to use `DomSanitizer` to sanitize url for XSS risk

Comment: Functionally this might be a good solution. Security wise it *might* be problematic though. Also, the payment website may not allow to be opened in a frame (via CSP header frame-ancestors).

Comment: Talon, As of now, we should load the payment page in the same window. The iframe way of integration is something we already thought of, but should not be doing that immediately as the client wants it the other way.

Answer (score 0):

in your constructor in page /search/details/id add these two line:

```
history.pushState(null, '', 'http://localhost:4200/search');
history.pushState(null, '', 'http://localhost:4200/search/details/id');
```

or in production:

```
history.pushState(null, '', 'https://your_domain/search');
history.pushState(null, '', 'https://your_domain/search/details/id');
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work